# why my values are not entering into the database

Tags: php

```
 /*My data is not inserted in the database */
   <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", '');
    mysqli_select_db($con,"test");

    if(isset($_POST['Submit']))

    {
    $num =$_POST['h'];

    for($i=0;$i<=$num;$i++)

    {

            $date       = $_POST["name_$i"];
            $name   = $_POST["address_$i"];
            $contactNum = $_POST["contactNum_$i"];
            $loan    = $_POST["loan_$i"];
            $status= $_POST["status_$i"];
        /*data is not stored in db and it doesn't show any error*/  

    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `com` Values('$date', '$name', '$contactNum','$loan','$status')");

    }

    echo "<h1>Do`enter code here`ne!</h1>";
    }
/*data is not inserted into db*/
    else
    {
        echo "not inserted";
    }
    ?
```

/* Initially only one row data is stored into database but actually I have 3 rows in my Html code*/
/*but now even my 1st row data is also not getting inserted*/

Comment: Seriously? Have you read ANY tutorials on how to do an `INSERT`-query?

Comment: ofcourse I have

Comment: Then you haven't understood them. Read them again, and modify the query. And add error-handling, then you would get why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**mysqli_query()** is execute only one query at a time.

> if you inserting multiple row in database at a time you want to user **For Loop** with no. of records.
>
> Another way is using **$conn->multi_query($sql)** method.
>
> For Example visit following link:[enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp)

Comment: ya even i gave for loop

Comment: plz help me out

Comment: Click on **link**